# phonegap Storage in iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to save some data and fetching that data from Database.

I have done all from [Here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/#comment-92635). But I am not getting list view here. just header are getting appears.

What I want my application to be is

[image]  and what I am getting is this ![image]

Don't know why but the control is not going in OnDeviceReady() method !!

EDIT : Here is the code of my .js file

```
var db;
var dbCreated = false;

alert("Hello 1 " );

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: false, hScrollbar:false, hScroll: false });

alert("Hello 2" );


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

alert("Hello 3" );

function onDeviceReady() 
{
 alert("Hello 4" );

db = window.openDatabase("EmployeeDirectoryDB", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
if (dbCreated)
    db.transaction(getEmployees, transaction_error);
else
    db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
}
```

and here is my html code

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee Directory</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />


  </head>

<body>

<div id="header" class="header">
    <h1>Employee Directory</h1>
</div>
<div id="header2">
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="employeeList" class="icon-list"></ul>
</div>

<div id="busy"/>Loading...</div>


    <SCRIPT >
        alert('Saving !!');
        </script>



    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/employeelist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js">    </script>
    <script src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/employeedetails.js"></script>
    <script src="js/reportlist.js"></script>
    <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>


    <!--
<script src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/employeelist.js"></script>

     -->
</body>

</html>
```

M getting just one popup - Hello 1.

After that no popup appears !!

I have tried using

```
 <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
```

and also on commenting the  var scroll control is not entering to th Device ready method ....

Pls Help !!

Comment: It would be great if you can share code that would be helpful then screenshots :)

Comment: I cant see ny.js included in your html page. Also there is a space in file name ny .js

Comment: I have added my all .js files just before ending of <body> and name of the file is employeelist.js

Comment: var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: false, hScrollbar:false, hScroll: false }); you are calling iscroll but file include is commented in your html ??

Comment: on commenting var scroll also nothing is happening !! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you add `<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>` above the .js file you embed up there,..

or remove `var scroll = new iScroll()`

Comment: I added <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script> but nothing happened !! :(

Comment: I've downloaded the sample file, it seems that it doesn't do anything with phonegap. It'just html5 database, you can find plenty [tutorials](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/) for that. If you have a running web server you can quickly test and debug by changing `<body onload="onDeviceReady()">` and exclude `phonegap.js` until you're ready to test on device.